# How to add different styles on different Items of ListView (AndroidStudio)?

Tags: java, android-studio, listview

I have ListView with a lot of items, and I want to create round corners. For it I have to use different styles for 1st and last items. How can I do it

Comment: First of all, use `RecyclerView`. Second of all, check out `viewTypes` and return a different viewType for 1st and last position. It should be relatively easy to do

Comment: Could you show us the code of what you have tried so far and where you are failing. This explanation is too shallow which makes it hard to answer your question